# Using VBA to Copy Multiple HTML tables from browser to Excel

Tags: html, vba, excel, file-copying

Sounds simple right?

I am working on a class project and I need a bunch of data from a bunch of .gov websites and I am struggling to get this to work reliably.

I was able to get this to work perfectly on tables where there was only text in the cells. I was able to do this with .innertext function of an HTML object (and of course I left my flashdrive at school so I can't see what I used, figures).

Anyway, my issue is that I cannot get the information from some cells when they contain links to other pages. For example, on this OPM site, https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/salaries-wages/2017/general-schedule/, there is the web option to view the form and I cannot get it to copy the web addresses into excel. Copying the text in the cells works fine but I cannot figure out how to make it copy the **href** text.

Does anyone happen to have any experience with this and could hopefully point me in the right direction?

Best,

Clueless Guy who is lost as usual.

Edit: Here is my code so far. I removed the bits about href because they were causing it not to work and were almost certainly incorrect.

Sub GetTables()
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim htmTable As HTMLTable
    Dim hpLink As IHTMLElement
    Dim data
        Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim oRow As Object, oCell As Object
    Dim oDom As Object: Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")

```
x = 1
y = 1
Set doc = New HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/salaries-wages/2017/general-schedule/"
    .send
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    .abort
End With

Set htmTable = doc.getElementsByClassName("DataTable")(0)

With htmTable
    Debug.Print .Rows(0).Cells(1).innerText
    Debug.Print .Rows(6).Cells(1).innerText
    Debug.Print .Rows(7).Cells(1).innerText

    ReDim data(1 To .Rows.Length, 1 To .Rows(1).Cells.Length)
    For Each oRow In .Rows
        For Each oCell In oRow.Cells

            data(x, y) = oCell.innerText
            'Previously, I had attempted to use oCell.href to get the value 
            'but that did not work.

            y = y + 1
        Next oCell
        y = 1
        x = x + 1
    Next oRow
End With

Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data
```

End Sub

Comment: When you find your flashdrive, update your question with the code you are currently using....

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I have updated it with the working code. I also have a copy of the code that did not work.